# Can't set footnote in Word doc using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have numerous WORD documents that have several Content Controls in them. I am using an Excel file to update the WORD docs. When I make an update, I need to insert a footnote describing the change. I can update the contents of the Content Control just fine, but I am having problems inserting the footnote. Here's my code:

```
Set cc = oRange.ContentControls(intCounter)
strOriginalDate = cc.Range.Text

If wrdDoc.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
    wrdDoc.Unprotect strSheetPassword
End If

If wrdDoc.FormsDesign = False Then
    wrdDoc.ToggleFormsDesign
End If
cc.Range.Text = strCOD
'
' Insert the footnote
'
oRange = wrdDoc.Range(cc.Range.End, cc.Range.End)
oRange.Select
Selection.MoveRight Units:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
Selection.TypeText Text:=" "
With Selection
    With .FootnoteOptions
        .Location = wdBottomOfPage
        .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
        .StartingNumber = 1
        .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
        .LayoutColumns = 0
    End With
    .Footnotes.Add Range:=cc.Range, Text:="Case Opening Date changed from " & _
    strOriginalDate & " to " & strCOD & " on " & Date, Reference:=""
    End If
End With

wrdDoc.ToggleFormsDesign
wrdDoc.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:=strSheetPassword
wrdDoc.Save
```

When I get down to the line `Selection.MoveRight Units:=wdCharacter, Count:=1`, I get an error that says `Object doesn't support this property or method`. In essence, I'm trying to move to the end of the control, then on the next step, I'm trying to move beyond/outside the control.

When I comment out that line and the line that follows it, I end up trying to insert the footnote into the content control. That fails on the `With .FootnoteOptions` line, possibly because the content control I'm using is a date picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that you can't add a footnote inside of a Content Control.  The solution is exactly what you are trying to do - put it in the document after.  The problem is that you are trying to add it using the Selection object.

Since you already have a Range within the context of the Document (oRange), just work with it directly:

```
'
' Insert the footnote
'

'Move the oRange to an "insertion point" after the control.
oRange.Start = cc.Range.End + 1
'Collapse it.
oRange.End = oRange.Start
'Add your space.
oRange.Text = " "

With oRange.FootnoteOptions
    .Location = wdBottomOfPage
    .NumberingRule = wdRestartContinuous
    .StartingNumber = 1
    .NumberStyle = wdNoteNumberStyleArabic
    .LayoutColumns = 0
End With

oRange.Footnotes.Add Range:=oRange, Text:="Case Opening Date changed from " & _
                     strOriginalDate & " to " & strCOD & " on " & Date
```

There's really no reason to be mucking around with the Selection - it's just a glorified Range with the added benefit of doing all the annoying things that Word does "for your benefit" (like grabbing the trailing space) while you're highlighting with the mouse.

I'll also note that you can omit the `Reference:=""` - it gets set to an empty string by default.  You also have a floating `End If` inside your With block.

Comment: Yes, this did the trick, thanks very much. I had used code hat Word generated, that's why I was all hung up on using the `Selection` object. I also had problems with the loop that surrounded this code - was running into problems with the StoryRanges, which was confusing me, too. The extra `End If` is from me "whittling down" the code to present to everyone. Anyhow, it's all working now, thanks again! Chuckles...